# Specifying a method parameter's type as singleton object's type

Tags: scala

I'd like to write a method that takes a specific singleton object type, like this:

```
object X
def foo(x: X.type) = ???    // this doesn't compile
```

However, this doesn't compile.

If you're wondering, my actual use case is the following:

```
class Outer { object Inner }
def foo(x: Outer#Inner.type) = ???    // this doesn't compile
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The first case does compile.

```
scala> object X
defined object X

scala> def foo(x: X.type) = ??? 
foo: (x: X.type)Nothing
```

The second case, I think the problem is a bit of syntactical deficiency. One work around it could be something like:

```
scala> class Outer { object Inner; type InnerType = Inner.type  }
defined class Outer

scala> def foo(x: Outer#InnerType) = ??? 
foo: (x: _1.Inner.type forSome { val _1: Outer })Nothing
```

Comment: Or just use `def foo(x: y.Inner.type forSome { val y: Outer })` in the first place. I wouldn't call this a "syntactical deficiency": `Outer#Inner.type` doesn't make sense because `Outer#Inner` doesn't denote a value.

Comment: You are right that `Outer#Inner` doesn't denote a value, but I feel some syntax sugar is missing there for this case.

Comment: I think it's supposed to parse as `Outer` `#` `Inner.type`. Not `Outer#Inner` `.` `type`. Though I realise that still doesn't make 100% sense.

Comment: Just realized, after looking at some other questions on SO, that Scala (singleton) objects do not define types. Any reason for this ? Do you have good resources about that ?